# Passport validity requirement to enter USA for travelling

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports

My visa will be expired December 12, 2017. 
However my passport will expire on **January 17**, 2016.

I wish to reach the USA border on **July 15**, 2015 to stay in the USA for 25 days. At that date my passport will be expired after 6 months and 2 days from **July 15**, 2015.

Is there any problem to get permission to enter USA for 25 days from the Immigration authority?

Comment: What's your nationality?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the country of your passport.

In general your passport has to be valid [six months past your *departure* from the US](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/826/kw/passport%20validity%206%20month). However, there is a lengthy [list of countries which are exempt from this requirement](https://fam.state.gov/fam/09FAM/09FAM040309.html#M403_9_3_B_2); for these countries the passport must be valid up to the date of departure.

The exempt list is 126 countries, covering most of the world, so I'm not reproducing it here.