# US B1-B2 visa expiring and travel to US

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

My visa is expiring in May 2016 and I want to visit USA in March to 2 weeks on a business trip. Can I run into any troubles or there be any issues in getting I-94 upon reaching USA.

Comment: What's your citizenship? And if you have a visa valid until May, why would you think there might be problems entering in March?

Comment: Perhaps you confuse with your [passport](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/572) needs to be valid "six months beyond the period of their intended stay in the U.S" but that says nothing about your visa.

Comment: Actually my passport and US B1/B2 Visa both are expiring in May 2016 and I want to visit US in March for two weeks. Do you see any issues with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passport validity requirement to enter USA for travelling](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48228/passport-validity-requirement-to-enter-usa-for-travelling)

Comment: It is NOT a duplicate of that question as this _question_ does not mention passport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question in your description is, yes, it's perfectly fine. The visa's expiration date means the last day on which you can use the visa to enter. So as long as you enter the US on the day the visa expires, or on any day before that, it's fine.

You also mentioned in your comments about your passport expiring (a coincidence?). Generally, people entering on nonimmigrant visas will need to have a passport valid for 6 months when entering the US, and their I-94 will be limited to 6 months before their passport expires. However, for people with passports from a [certain list of countries](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040309.html#M403_9_3_B_2), they only need to have a passport valid at the time of entry, and the I-94 will be limited to the passport's date of expiration.

Comment: I am Indian citizen and both my passport and US visa are expiring in May 2016. If I am travelling in March, my passport is not meeting 6 month's passport validity requirement.  Thank you for your response in advance.

Comment: @Sam: But you are using an Indian passport which does not need to meet the 6-month validity requirement, because India is in that list of countries. It just needs to be valid on the day you enter, and your I-94 will be limited to the day your passport expires.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all this valuable information. Very much appreciated !! :)