# Passport expiring in 2 months, but US VISA is valid

Tags: visas, usa, passports, indian-citizens

I have a US VISA valid till 2019.
But my passport is expiring on 20th July 2016.
I would like to travel to US in the month of June & 
**I got the confirmation from USVISA that Indian passport need not have 6 months validity.**

But now one of the travel agent has raised a query that std rule is 6 month validity.

Indian immigration dept not able to answer the query properly
Can someone guide me with the exact rule.

Comment: Duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/48228/32134 but the link in that A is broken. Refer to http://www.immihelp.com/visas/six-months-passport-validity-rule-visitors.html for now. In short: you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

The most recent document I could find from an official source is this one, dated July 16, 2015 and posted to the CBP web site on August 11, 2015.  An excerpt:

> Citizens of the countries listed below are exempt from the six-month rule and need only have a passport valid for their intended period of stay.
>
> ...
>   India
>   ...

One reason this information is hard to find is that it is intended for "carriers," such as airline companies.

Another great way to check these requirements is TIMATIC.  Certain airlines have a web page allowing you to query TIMATIC; the pages are generally labeled along the lines of "check visa requirements for your trip."

For example, on KLM's website, you can follow "prepare for your trip," and then "passport and visa," and then, under "which travel documents do I need," there's a button for "check your trip."  It links to their [TIMATIC query form](https://www.klm.com/travel/nl_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/visaform.htm).

Specifying India for both nationality and embarkation, and United States for destination country, I got, in part, the following:

> Passport required.
>   - Passports issued to nationals of India must be valid for the
>     period of intended stay.

So it seems that anyone who's telling you that it must be valid for six months beyond your period of intended stay is incorrect.